copyLamdaFunction creating is failing when i try to deploy Data Lake in AWS
Iam trying to deploy data lake on AWS using the source : https://aws-ia.github.io/cfn-ps-datalake-foundation/ but iam getting error.
Data-lake-foundation-DataLakeFoundationStack-IS67G4LRJQIU-ElasticsearchStack-YY9NNQARTKAR
CREATE_FAILED
The following resource(s) failed to create: [CopyLambdaDeployment].
Cloud Watch Logs :
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied
What is the solution for this?
Please find the screenshots.enter image description here
I tried add IAM permissions, according to the solutions received but none of them worked.
IAM Permissions for a role to deploy data lake.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::datalake-submissions/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::datalake-curated-datasets/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::datalake-published-data/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::regional-lambda-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::datalake-athena-query-results/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:*",
                "kinesisanalytics:*",
                "lambda:*",
                "glue:*",
                "kinesis:CreateStream",
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:PutRecord",
                "kinesis:PutRecords",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "athena:*",
                "redshift:*",
                "quicksight:*",
                "sns:*",
                "sagemaker:*",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream",
                "firehose:ListDeliveryStreams",
                "firehose:PutRecord",
                "firehose:PutRecordBatch",
                "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplate",
                "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:DescribeParameters",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "logs:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "es:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My specific probelm is like, iam unable to deploy data lake due to copyObject access denied error. i tried adding IAM plolicies laso.

In order to perform CopyObject action you need the below permissions: 
s3:GetObject 
s3:PutObject 
s3express:CreateSession
You might also need: 
s3:PutObjectTagging 
s3:ListBucket 
s3:PutObjectTagging
For using create session you're account should have those permissions: 
s3express:DeleteBucket 
s3express:DeleteBucketPolicy 
s3express:CreateBucket 
s3express:PutBucketPolicy 
s3express:GetBucketPolicy 
s3express:ListAllMyDirectoryBuckets

When i tried to add that, it showing as invalid action in json.

You right, editing my answer

I have added, if though its failing.

I didn't understand, is it still failing? Can you share the messages? The iam role, policy and to what resources and account you added them?
